# putty - psftp connection refused

Tags: putty

Im trying to connect with PSFTP.exe but I got error, if I do the same in FTP in cmd line or Filezilla it works good. I have tried other ftps but nobody works.

```
  C:\putty>psftp.exe ftp.mozilla.org
  Fatal: Network error: Connection refused
```

Any suggestions? Do I need to start putty.exe or configure psftp in some way that I have missing?

Im working in Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

That's because PSFTP is not an [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) client, it's an [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) client. Different protocols.

Comment: Ok, then I cant use PSFTP for or?

Comment: Not for an FTP server. I can't think of any publicly available SFTP servers, but they are common in private networks (I use them at both home and work).